# pubspec.yaml has no lower-bound SDK constraint. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Why I am getting this error? **pubspec.yaml has no lower-bound SDK constraint. You should edit pubspec.yaml to contain an SDK constraint:**

```
name: flutter_nfc_reader
description: A nfc reader plugin for iOS and Android. This plugin allow you to trigger NFC native reading session on device.
version: 0.1.2
author: Matteo Crippa <matteocrippa>
homepage: https://github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader
publish_to: 'none'
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.19.0 <3.0.0'
  flutter: ^0.1.2

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  plugin:
    androidPackage: it.matteocrippa.flutternfcreader
    pluginClass: FlutterNfcReaderPlugin
```

Comment: It looks like you might be using an old version of Flutter (1.19.0?). I ran your pubspec and it works without errors other than the android plugin, which I don't have access to. I would clean, and look at the current pubspec documentation. I also don't believe you need the flutter value under enviroment, but you may have a special reason for that.

Comment: 1.19 is dart from a few years ago (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1190---2016-08-26).  Dart hit 2.0 when flutter was released.